# Drop / move header of a dataframe into first row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe who looks like this:

```
  A   B   10
0 A   B   20
1 C   A   10
```

so the headers are not the real headers of the dataframe (I have to map them from another dataframe), how can I drop the headers in this case into the first row, that it looks like this:

```
  0   1   2
0 A   B   10
1 A   B   20
2 C   A   10
```

*Note that `pd.read_csv(..., header=None)` leads to an error in this case, I don't know why, so I am searching for a solution to fix it after I load the file.*

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: rowline error, but it doesn't really matter as I am searching for an alternative solution instead of adjusting the command `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best is avoid it by `header=None` parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
```

If not possible append columns names converted to one row `DataFrame` to original data and then set `range` to columns names:

```
df = df.columns.to_frame().T.append(df, ignore_index=True)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
print (df)
   0  1   2
0  A  B  10
1  A  B  20
2  C  A  10
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `reset_index` for fixing

```
df = df.T.reset_index().T
```

Comment: first index will named index in that case, and I must agree its a little slower then Jezrael solutions, thx for this alternativ